# Selecting only certain rows while opening text file in pandas

Tags: python, text, pandas

I have a text file that is tab delimited for the first 80 rows, and these are the only rows I need in the file.  I would normally open the file like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t')
```

but this returns the error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 84, saw 81
```

because somewhere along the way it is no longer tab delimited Im pretty sure.  If I manually delete everything in the file except for the first 80 rows I can set the tab delimiter and it reads fine, but I need to do this for lots of files.   I know I can select only the first 80 using this:

```
df=df.iloc[:80,:]
```

but then my dataframe has `\t` separating every column instead of a space like I want.  Is there a way to select only the first 80 rows while opening the file so then I can set `sep='\t'` without the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify just to read the first 80 rows using param [`nrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t', nrows=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set error parameter True which will drop the blank or malformed lines. nrows is not suitable as per my view because you have to manually add the row count for each file.

```
    df=pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
```

You can also go through these attributes

> warn_bad_lines
>
> skip_blank_lines

[Folow this link to read more](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: I will look into this too, nrows did work for me though so they must already be specified

Comment: yeah sure, all the best